# How do I stop a timed event from happening?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game where a user clicks on insects and tries to get a good high score. When the user clicks on one insect, the insect plays an animation and stays in its spot for 2 seconds in this code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.motion.Animator;
import flash.events.*;
play();
var mysound:squish = new squish(); 
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
this.dead = false;
function kill(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    this.dead=true;
    mouseChildren=false
    mysound.play();
    gotoAndPlay(21);
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kill);
    flash.utils.setTimeout(removeSelf,2000);

}

function removeSelf():void
{
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

When the user pauses the game, the enemies are stopped and they turn invisible. The only problem is that when the user clicks on the insects, and hits the pause button, the insects stay there for 2 seconds. How do I remove the timer when the person pauses the game so that no insects are on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

A few tips:

- Never use timeouts, they will produce poor, unsustainable, hard to debug code. Use Timer instead. Timer provides nice little features like: repeat times, pausing, resuming and resetting the timer. So you could set the timers timeout to 2000ms, repeat once and set an event listener TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE to remove the insect etc. You can pause the timer when you pause the game and resume when needed.
- If you do however use timeouts, assign a uint to it and use a clearTimeout() method to stop it.
- construction such as  `this.parent.removeChild(this);` is ugly. Instead, dispatch an event as an alternative and let the parent to manage the dead bugs (remove from arrays, display list etc).
- Storing a sound in every bugs instance will take way more memory than needed. Make a static sound library class and call the play() method from it.